# Pandas: how to convert an incomplete date-only index to hourly index

Tags: python, pandas

I have an ideal hourly time series that looks like this:

```
from pandas import Series, date_range, Timestamp
from numpy import random

index = date_range(
    "2020-01-26 14:00:00",
    "2020-11-28 02:00:00",
    freq="H",
    tz="Europe/Madrid",
)
ideal = Series(index=index, data=random.rand(len(index)))
ideal
```

> ```
> 2020-01-26 14:00:00+01:00    0.186026
> 2020-01-26 15:00:00+01:00    0.142096
> 2020-01-26 16:00:00+01:00    0.432625
> 2020-01-26 17:00:00+01:00    0.373805
> 2020-01-26 18:00:00+01:00    0.377718
>                                ...   
> 2020-11-27 22:00:00+01:00    0.961327
> 2020-11-27 23:00:00+01:00    0.440274
> 2020-11-28 00:00:00+01:00    0.996126
> 2020-11-28 01:00:00+01:00    0.607873
> 2020-11-28 02:00:00+01:00    0.122993
> Freq: H, Length: 7357, dtype: float64
> ```

The actual, non-ideal time series is far from perfect:

- It is not complete (i.e.: some hourly values are missing)
- Only the date is stored, not the hour

Something like this:

```
actual = ideal.drop([
    Timestamp("2020-01-28 01:00:00", tz="Europe/Madrid"),
    Timestamp("2020-08-02 15:00:00", tz="Europe/Madrid"),
    Timestamp("2020-08-02 16:00:00", tz="Europe/Madrid"),
])
actual.index = actual.index.date
actual
```

> ```
> 2020-01-26    0.186026
> 2020-01-26    0.142096
> 2020-01-26    0.432625
> 2020-01-26    0.373805
> 2020-01-26    0.377718
>                 ...   
> 2020-11-27    0.961327
> 2020-11-27    0.440274
> 2020-11-28    0.996126
> 2020-11-28    0.607873
> 2020-11-28    0.122993
> Length: 7355, dtype: float64
> ```

Now I would like to convert the actual time series into something as close as possible to the ideal. That means:

- The resulting series has a full hourly index (i.e.: no missing values)
- NaNs are allowed if there is no way to fill an hour (i.e.: it is missing in the actual time series)
- Misalignment within a day with respect to the ideal time series is expected only in those days with missing data

Is there an efficient way to do this? I would like to avoid having to iterate since I am guessing that would be very inefficient.

With efficient I am looking for a fast (CPU wall time) implementation that relies only on Python/Pandas/NumPy (no Cython or Numba allowed).

Comment: The problem is on `2020-08-02` you have 22 rows. How do you know, from the `actual` that `15:00:00` and `16:00:00`, instead of `1:00:00` and `10:00:00`, are missing?

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't know, and I would not care. As mentioned, misalignment within a day with respect to the ideal time series is expected in those days with missing data. That means I know 2 values will be missing, but I would not care if they are put at the beginning of the day, at the end or in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby().cumcount()` to represent the hour within a day then reindex:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(actual.index).tz_localize("Europe/Madrid").to_series()
actual.index = s + s.groupby(level=0).cumcount() * pd.Timedelta('1H')

new_idx = pd.date_range(actual.index.min(),actual.index.max(), freq='H')
actual = actual.reindex(new_idx)
```

Comment: I think I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` if I just execute the code you provided, but I get the idea, thanks a lot! ^^ Can you update the answer to avoid this error before accepting?

Comment: I'm looking at the error as well. It might be due to daylight preserving time, happens with two `2020-10-27 01:00:00` timestamps.

Comment: Yeah, I am using `tz="Europe/Madrid"` and because of DST, that may happen (I intentionally left the DST days unaltered since one of them is 25 hours and with a "duplicate" hour).

Comment: I edited your answer to fix the localized index, hope you don't mind. Thanks again! ^^

Comment: @Peque thanks, that was simple. I learn a new thing.